# why is there different syntax same outcome?

Tags: php, syntax, loops, shortcode

Why is there different syntax same outcome?

For example

```
# Example 1
if($myCondition == true) :
    #my code here
endif;

if($myCondition == true) {
    #my code here
}

# Example 2
foreach($films as $film) : 
    #my code here
endforeach;

foreach($films as $film) { 
    #my code here
}
```

Also I have been using `<?=` for ages now and I now understand that is deprecated and I should be using `<?php echo` Is this the case and why? It's a lot more annoying to have to write that out each time.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: If you have to write `<?php echo ...; ?>` more than a few times, use a template engine. Having html and php code in the same file is extremely dirty.

Comment: @ThiefMaster PHP by itself is a template engine. Whether you write `{$smartySucks}` or `<?php echo $someVar; ?>` doesn't matter. It only gets dirty when you start to mix logic into the template.

Comment: @Gordon Something about your example seems biased :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colon endif, endforeach, etc syntax is known as [Alternative Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). I can't say for certain why this functionality exists, just that it does and is supported. I can say that I've noticed the alternative syntax used more for templating purposes where it's easy to pick out an endif/endforeach than it is a closing curly-brace in the middle of HTML markup.

The `<?=` is known as the short open tag. You can probably find all the info you need about its use here [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

Answer (score 1):

Why should the outcome be different? The one without the brackets is called [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) and is very useful, e.g. when dealing with HTML.

`<?php echo` is much more portable because short open tags can be disabled and are disabled by default since PHP 5.3

Comment: disabled by default, but is it still supported or is it deprecated?

Comment: @Lizard it is deprecated. But it won't be removed. See the links given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413661/php6-is-short-open-tag-removed-or-deprecated-or-neither